# Bash script working fine but not as cronjob - Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, bash, cron, raspberry-pi

I want to backup some audio files from my Raspberry Pi to a mounted network share (SMB). I've put together this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S');
sudo rsync -a -v /home/pi/davisbot/audio/ /mnt/resources/davisbot_audios/ --log-file=davislog.log
sudo cp -rv /home/pi/davislog.log /mnt/resources/davisbot_audios/"$dt"davislog.log
```

When I run the script, it works perfectly and instantly backups said files to the share. My cron job however doesnt work (Contents of crontab -e):

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/pi/davisbackup.sh
* * * * * /home/pi/davisbackup.sh
```

In the first line I've put the PATH variable because someone told me it might help, unfortunately it didn't. Also I've tried this:

```
* * * * * bash -lc /home/pi/davisbackup.sh
```

which also didn't help. I used `sudo service cron restart` during every try. What is left that I can try? Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try taking out :/home/pi/davisbackup.sh from the PATH

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command

Comment: Thanks @RamanSailopal it finally works!!